# Can't seem to get RegEx to match

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to extract the `Get-Help` comment headers from a PowerShell script...using PowerShell. The file I'm reading looks something like this:

```
<#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Synopsis goes here.
        It could span multiple lines.
        Like this.

    .DESCRIPTION 
        A description.
        It could also span multiple lines.

    .PARAMETER MyParam
        Purpose of MyParam

    .PARAMETER MySecondParam
        Purpose of MySecondParam.
        Notice that this section also starts with '.PARAMETER'.
        This one should not be captured.

    ...and many many more lines like this...
#>

# Rest of the script...
```

I would like to get all the text below `.DESCRIPTION`, up to the first instance of `.PARAMETER`. So the desired output would be:

```
A description.
It could also span multiple lines.
```

Here's what I've tried:

```bsh
$script = Get-Content -Path "C:\path\to\the\script.ps1" -Raw
$pattern = '\.DESCRIPTION(.*?)\.PARAMETER'

$description = $script | Select-String -Pattern $pattern

Write-Host $description
```

When I run that, `$description` is empty. If I change `$pattern` to `.*`, I get the entire contents of the file, as expected; So there must be something wrong with my RegEx pattern, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(get-help get-date).description

The `Get-Date` cmdlet gets a DateTime object that represents the current date 
or a date that you specify. It can format the date and time in several Windows 
and UNIX formats. You can use `Get-Date` to generate a date or time character 
string, and then send the string to other cmdlets or programs.

(get-help .\script.ps1).description
```

Comment: I'm trying to extract it from a script I wrote, it's not an installed module. But cool trick!

Comment: `(get-help .\script.ps1).description`

Comment: Oh wow, just tested that and it worked. Even simpler, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

the `Select-String` cmdlet works on *entire strings* and you have given it ONE string. [*grin*]

so, instead of fighting with that, i went with the `-match` operator. the following presumes you have loaded the entire file into `$InStuff` as one multiline string with `-Raw`.

the `(?ms)` stuff is two regex flags - multiline & singleline.

```
$InStuff -match '(?ms)(DESCRIPTION.*?)\.PARAMETER'

$Matches.1
```

output ...

```
DESCRIPTION 
        A description.
        It could also span multiple lines.
```

note that there is a blank line at the end. you likely will want to trim that away.

Comment: Disregard my last comment, this worked, I somehow pointed it at a script that didn't have a `DESCRIPTION` header when I tested this solution. Upvoted, thanks for your help! P.S. When you said `works on entire strings and you have given it ONE string` did you mean that it works on a collection of strings and I only gave it one string? Just making sure I understand what you meant.

Comment: @LewsTherin - you are quite welcome! [*grin*] ///// when you use `Get-Content -Raw` you get ONE multiline string. try doing a `.GetType()` on it. when you use `Get-Content` _without the `-Raw` parameter_, you get an array of single-line strings. the way `Select-String` works is to select _entire strings_ ... and if you give it ONE string ... then it will find -at most - ONE string. [*grin*]

Answer (score 3):

In the words of [@Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56605007/2150063):

> **Don't use regex to parse PowerShell code in PowerShell**
>
> Use the PowerShell parser instead!

So, let's use PowerShell to parse PowerShell:

```
$ScriptFile = "C:\path\to\the\script.ps1"

$ScriptAST = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseFile($ScriptFile, [ref]$null, [ref]$null)

$ScriptAST.GetHelpContent().Description
```

We use the `[System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseFile()` to parse our file and ouput an Abstract Syntax Tree (AST).

Once we have the Abstract Syntax Tree, we can then use the `GetHelpContent()` method (exactly what `Get-Help` uses) to get our parsed help content.

Since we are only interested in the `Description` portion, we can simply access it directly with `.GetHelpContent().Description`

Comment: oooo! that is so very nifty! [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I thought you would like that ;-)

Comment: i'm playing with the AST stuff right  now. i had entirely forgotten there was such a thing ... [*grin*]

Comment: I had no idea you could do this, cool! I'll try this approach out, thank you!